# How to get list of tasks specific to assigned user & projects from Asana in php?

Tags: php, asana

How would I get the list of tasks (based on its status) from asana in php which is filtered on user (assigned to) and projects.

e.g.: Suppose a workspace: WSA1 have projects P1, P2, P3... and I have Users as U1, U2... assigned to the task randomly in each of the projects.

Now I want to get:

1. List of task for user1 from project P1 (if tasks exists)
2. List of task for user1 from project P2 (if tasks exists) and so on...
3. List of task for user2 from project P1 (if tasks exists)
4. List of task for user2 from project P2 (if tasks exists) and so on...

I am able to get List of all the tasks from the projects, where I can iterate through those arrays and will get the user specific tasks, but is there some direct way to get the desired output with less execution processing and timing?

Comment: We don't currently have a way to do advanced filtering, but we are looking into building support for search into the API - is it possible to get the views you need via the current in-product search?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be able to get what you want with a query in the form of `/tasks?assignee=$assignee&project=$project`. Let me know if that works for you!